# ViewController with several behaviour models

Tags: ios, architecture

Assume I have two viewcontrollers. On the first viewcontroller I need to select one of N options and depending on this option second viewcontroller has a different behaviour. In practice I can call same methods, but with different implementations, but I don't want to pass argument (enum) describing the current mode of viewcontroller in every method or making a switch everytime. What is the most relevant design solution for this case?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your value of N (options on first view controller) and how much the differ from each other.

If N is smaller and are more different then each other then you should have separate view controller for your second screen. You can use inheritance if differences are not much.

If N is large then you should categorise your N option and have a controller for each category and you can use enums/flags for customisation with in a category.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Inheritance. Write a base class and override base method to adapt with each child controller.